# Find Expiry date of Deal in relation table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relation, subquery

I have a category table in which I have different categories of deals. Each of them consists of many deals along with its expiry date. I want to access only those deals with their categories whose expiry date is not over, but I am getting an issue that if any deal of category exists in time range all of its deals arrive whether it's expired or not. Here is my code:

```
$deals = DealCategory::where('name', '!=', 'Today Deal')
        ->whereRelation('deals','start_date', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))
        ->whereRelation('deals', 'expiry_date',">=", date('Y-m-d'))
        ->with('deals', 'deals.deal_images', 'deals.deal_products', 'deals.deal_products.product', 'deals.rating')->latest()->Paginate(12);
        return response()->json(['Deals' => $deals, 'Date' => Carbon::now(), 'status' => 'success'], 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you eagerly load relations using `with`, you can pass additional criteria to tell Eloquent which records to load:

```
DealCategory::where('name', '!=', 'Today Deal')
  ->whereRelation('deals','start_date', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))
  ->whereRelation('deals', 'expiry_date',">=", date('Y-m-d'))
  ->with(['deals' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('start_date', '<=', date('Y-m-d'));
    $query->where('expiry_date',">=", date('Y-m-d'));
    $query->with('deal_images', 'deal_products', 'deal_products.product', 'rating');
  }])
->latest()->Paginate(12);
```

Latest versions of Laravel even include a dedicated `withWhereHas`  method to check for the existence of a relationship while simultaneously loading the relationship based on the same conditions:

```
DealCategory::where('name', '!=', 'Today Deal')
  ->withWhereHas('deals', function ($query) {
    $query->where('start_date', '<=', date('Y-m-d'));
    $query->where('expiry_date',">=", date('Y-m-d'));
    $query->with('deal_images', 'deal_products', 'deal_products.product', 'rating');
  })
->latest()->Paginate(12);
```

Either option should do what you need.

Comment: I tried both but it still gives that issue if 1 category has 8 products and the condition becomes true in any one case it brings all 8 records in that case despite that one record.

Comment: The solution above filters the `deals` that will be returned. `deal_products` returned will be the ones that belong to returned deals. If you want to filter those as well, you'll need to add similar logic on `deal_products` relation.